# Ханойская башня, вопрос про последовательность вызовов

Tags: c, рекурсия

Всем привет! Не дает покоя задача... Я не могу понять последовательность вызовов в функции Ханои. Не кидайтесь, Я в курсе что есть 1000 уже решенных примеров про Башню, и в Ютубе полно роликов что рус что англ видео, но везде расписывается только сам алгоритм... и бац, у нас все работает, урок окончкен! Я не могу понять последовательность вызовов в самой функции, если в ней есть 2 рекурсии.  просто объясните как будто первоклашке какая функция вызывается и за кем она следует. Можно пожалуйста по пунктикам если не сложно.
Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void towers(int, char, char, char);

int main()
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter the number of disks : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("The sequence of moves involved in the Tower of Hanoi are :\n");
    towers(num, 'A', 'C', 'B');
    return 0;
}
void towers(int num, char frompeg, char topeg, char auxpeg)
{
    /* 1. Запуск Программы. Вводим значение num к примеру 3. 
       Вызывается функция void towers(3,'A','B','C');
       2. Переходим к самой функции. Наш num равен 3, так что машина
       пропускает случай if(num==1) и движется дальше. Мы встречаем 
       towers(num-1) и вот тут по подробнее бы... прям в деталях. Благодарю!

    */
      if (num == 1)
    {
        printf("\n Move disk 1 from peg %c to peg %c", frompeg, topeg);
        return;
    }
    towers(num - 1, frompeg, auxpeg, topeg);
    printf("\n Move disk %d from peg %c to peg %c", num, frompeg, topeg);
    towers(num - 1, auxpeg, topeg, frompeg);
}
```

Comment: Пока есть стопка на frompeg - перемещаем ее без последнего диска на auxpeg, после чего переносим этот самый большой диск  с frompeg на topeg, и теперь переносим все диски с auxpeg на topeg поверх перенесенного... Как переносим уменьшенную стопку? да точно так же - рекурсивно :) Просто не могу придумать, что тут еще детальнее рассказать...

Comment: Спасибо за фидбек, я поясню. У нас есть аргументы функции num, A, C, B;  В самой функции towers, есть еще 1 towers, эти самые аргументы переставляются или накладываются друг на друга? Глупые вопросы, просто я бездарен) и еще в самой функции есть 2 hanoi, они выполняются одновременно, то есть вызывается 1 Printf из одной hanoi потом вычитывается 1 из num потом второй printf из второй hanoi ?

Comment: Функция переносит num дисков со стойки - второго аргумента (frompeg) на стойку-третий аргумент (topeg) используя последнюю стойку как вспомогательную. В рекурсивных вызовах функции стоек меняются - первый вызов переносит с from на вспомогательную, последний - со вспомогательной на целевую.

Answer (score 1):

В общем сам отвечу. Как оказалось текстом, по крайней мере мне, было трудно представить. Я не мог понять саму последовательность вызовов, сам алгоритм вроде понятный. Если кто-то кто хочет не просто написать и чтобы типо рекурсия сама разбереться, а прям наглядно что за кем вызывается в такой вот рекурсии вот рисуночек:
[image]
S - sourse или FROM D - destination A- auximaly или temp